# Commutative diagram question

Tags: category-theory

[image]

Suppose outer square in above diagram is comutative i.e., $c\circ q\circ p=s\circ r\circ a$

Further, suppose right side square is commutative i.e., $c\circ q=s\circ b$?

Does it imply left side square is commutative i.e., $b\circ p=r\circ a$??

If $s$ has an inverse, it follows trivially. Are there other conditions that confirm this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, no. If $F$ is a terminal object, then the whole diagram and the right square commute automatically (since all composites to $F$ are the unique morphism to the terminal object), and then the left-hand square can be anything at all, commutative or otherwise.

If $s$ is monic, then the left-hand square commutes, since
$$s \circ r \circ a = c \circ q \circ p = s \circ b \circ p \quad \Rightarrow \quad r \circ a = b \circ p$$

In fact, $s$ being monic is, in a sense, *equivalent* to the condition in your question. Indeed, suppose $s$ is fixed and, for all such diagrams with $s$ in the bottom-right, commutativity of the outer and right squares implies commutativity of the left-hand square. We prove that $s$ is monic.

So let $f,g : B \to E$ and suppose $s \circ f = s \circ g$. Form the diagram with $a=p=q=\mathrm{id}_B$, $b=f$, $r=g$ and $c = s \circ f$. Then the right-hand square commutes trivially and the outer square commutes since $s \circ f = s \circ g$. Hence the left-hand square commutes, and so $f=g$. So $s$ is monic.

Comment: :) If $s$ is monic, it follows trivially just because of the definition.. I should have added this along with "If $s$ is invertible, it follows immediately"...Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The condition that $s$ is monic does not imply that $s$ is invertible (or even that $s$ has a left-inverse—that's *split* monic). I've updated my answer to prove that, relative to fixed $s$, the condition in your question is equivalent to the assertion that $s$ is monic.

Comment: I dont know whats split monic.. I only know monic and that means it has left inverse.. So, I said for monic it follows... what is monic for you if not left invertible arrow?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Having a left inverse implies monic, but being monic does not imply having a left inverse. See [monic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monomorphism) versus [split monic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+monomorphism) on nLab, and also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism). In some categories (e.g. the category of sets) all monomorphisms are split, but that is not the case in all categories. I don't know of any credible source on category theory that defines 'monomorphism' to mean 'has a left inverse'.

Comment: Ok Ok... An arrow $g$ is monic if $g\circ f=g\circ h$ implies $f=h$... An arrow $g$ is called split monic if there exists an arrow $t$ such that $t\circ g=1$... Suppose $g$ is split monic and $g\circ f=g\circ h$.. We have $t\circ g\circ f=t\circ g\circ h$.. As $t\circ g=1$, we have $f=h$... YOu are only using  monic in your answer... Though this is not what I expected, this is interesting :) :) Thanks, I learned some new terminology.. :) In some sense, having a section  of $s$ confirms what I asked.. :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: My answer uses/proves that $s$ is *monic*, not that it is split monic. Nowhere have I introduced a left inverse for $s$. Left-cancellation (monicity) does not imply the existence of a left-inverse.

Comment: That was a mistake. I mean to say monic.. got confused with wording...

Comment: I think nothing more can be said about the situation in the question.... It is likely to be the case that $s$ is monic... So, I accepted the answer..

Comment: I do not understand why you said "The condition that s is monic does not imply that s is invertible".. I did not said tha monic imply invertible... My statement "I only know monic and that means it has left inverse" is wrong.. When I said monic I had in mind $g\circ f=g\circ h$ implies $f=h$ but I said something else...